# Как сделать оптимизацию загрузки js и css

Tags: php, gzip, минификация

gzip включен, слышал что если минифицировать css и js файлы и создать их в бинарные файлики (.gz) то ускорится работа сервера. Вот у [php](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gzwrite.php) есть  gzwrite функция ней можно записывать такие данные, но каким образом сервер будет их считывать или как их правильно использовать для ускорения работы сайта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Один и тот же объём стилей/скриптов в одном запросе будет переадн быстрее, чем в нескольких. Ну при разумном объёме (а если он неразумный, то тебе оптимизации не помогут).
2. Минификация позволит уменьшить объем пересылаемого кода за счёт, как минимум, исключения ненужных пробелов. Для джаваскрипта также возможно изменение имён локальных переменных и некоторые другие штуки с целью его дополнительного сжатия.
3. Сжатие (например, gzip) уменьшает имеющийся объем архивацией. Это ускоряет его передачу по сети, но браузеру будет нужно время на распаковку. В идеале стоит оценить это время и принять решение, нужно ли использовать сжатие.
4. Сжатие на лету использует ресурсы сервера. Лучше выполнить его один раз и пока файл не меняется просто пересылать готовый сжатый вариант. По идее, используемый тобой сервер должен уметь это делать сам, если включить сжатие в настройках.
5. Пункт 4 касается и минификации. Однако, минификация обычно выполняется в процессе построения, а не указывается в настройках сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Есть библиотека [Minify](https://code.google.com/p/minify/), её просто подключаете к своей странице и указываете какие файлы сжимать.
Например:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://site.ru/min/index.php?charset=UTF-8&amp;b=template/css&amp;f=style1.css,style2.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.ru/min/index.php?charset=UTF-8&amp;b=template/js&amp;f=project.js,project2.js" charset='UTF-8'></script>
```

И для более быстрой загрузки страницы лучше js подключать перед закрывающим тегом body, так браузер быстрее загрузить страницу для пользователя, а потом начнет загрузку js.