# Дешифровка javascript

Tags: javascript

1. Зачем криптуют JS файлы? Полазив по сайтам, вижу, что на 1 из 10 есть закриптованный Javascript. Разве в нем может быть полезная информация?
2. http://pastebin.com/Upqy9xmx - как пример один из файлов , который закодирован.
   Есть ли возможность узнать чем он закодирован, и есть ли возможность расшифровать его без потери данных?

Comment: Мне просто любопытно, а зачем вам исходный (не минифицированный) файл? Что-то мне подсказывает, что речь идет о часто используемых библиотеках которые есть в свободном доступе...

Answer (score 6):

Можно. Это не шифрование, а минимизация файла. Чем файл меньше - тем бытрее он подгружается.
Вот онлайновский деминимизатор: http://unminify.com/
Есть еще много похожих.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать. Жалко, что нельзя полный код восстановить.

Comment: Незачто :) Обозначте пожалуйста правильный ответ..

Answer (score 4):

Обычно это всего лишь минификация. Делается при сборке с помощью Grunt/Gulp плагинов вроде Uglify.js. Так же, этот же плагин имеет метод Beautify) и делает всё ровно наоборот, т.е. превращает код обратно в читабельный.

На счет того, может ли быть в JS что-то полезное, конечно может. Особенно если дело касается игр например.

Так же могут помочь [Source Maps](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148098/), если они есть.

Comment: А каким образом можно полностью восстановить код не имея исходника? Сайт например, что дали ниже - восстанавливает только до сокращения каждой переменной, функции и т.п.

Comment: Только при наличии такой штуки как Source Maps. Почитать тут http://habrahabr.ru/post/148098/

Answer (score 0):

Это не шифрование, а минификация. Нужна для [оптимизации загрузки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451289/178988).

А шифрование бесполезно и выглядит как-то так:

```
eval(({}+[])[+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+({}+[])[+!![]
]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[]
)[+!![]+!![]+!![]]+({}+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]+!![]
]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+'.
'+(![]+[])[+!![]+!![]]+({}+[])[+!![]]+'g'+'('+'"'+'T'
+([][[]]+[])[+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!!
[]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]+!![]+!
![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]+!![]+!![]]+'"'+')')
```

Мне было лень искать онлайн-шифровальщик, так что воспользовался своим [отсюда](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40161/32091).
До eval'а можно тоже неявно добраться. И до других букв.